# html select top.location.href - strange IE issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am getting a strange issue only in IE with html <select> and <option>. The code reads..

```
<select class="logo" name="logoControl" id="logoControl" tabindex="1" onChange="top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
<option selected="selected" value="">My URL1</option>
<option value="http://google.com">My URL2</option>
<option value="http://facebook.com" >My URL3</option>
<option value="http://twitter.com">My URL4</option>
</select>
```

The above code is supposed to be my application logo and a select link. The default  "selected" link being my application and the other select options refer to external websites.
This works pretty well in Firefox and Chrome. Whereas, in IE, I face the following issue:
when I click any of my application menus, I am directed to the appropriate url. But, after navigating to that url, if I click the above select box for "My URL1", IE cuts off the URL when it sees a second "/" after the hostname.. ie., say if menu url is

```
"http://myhost.com/path1/path2.do?param1="
```

IE cuts it to:

```
"http://myhost.com/path1/"
```

On click of my application menu, it works fine. This error happens only onclick of the first select option mentioned above. ie., instead of remaining in the same page, IE attempts to cut-off the URL upto the second "/" and tries loading the page.

Could someone suggest me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this indirectly by adding the below two steps:

1) Disable my first select option ie., "My URL1"

```
<option selected="selected" value="" disabled="disabled">My URL1</option>
```

2) On load, make "My URL1" as "selected", so that when we navigate to other urls like "My URL2" or "My URL3" etc., and click "Back" button, we come back to the same location in "My URL1" and the select box logo also reads "My URL1"

```
document.getElementById("logoControl").options[0].selected="selected";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onchange is excessive. Try this:

```
<select class="logo" name="logoControl" id="logoControl" tabindex="1" onchange="top.location.href=this.value">
    <option selected="selected" value="">My URL1</option>
    <option value="http://google.com">My URL2</option>
    <option value="http://facebook.com" >My URL3</option>
    <option value="http://twitter.com">My URL4</option>
</select>
```